# How do I connect to an outside database from python?

Tags: python, mysql

I have a question here, I'm new at python and just installed it in my computer. So, How do I connect with my MySQL database, I've made some search and discovered that I need a Library to do it, but every time I try the

```
import MySQLdb as pymysql
```

It shows the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-3b863ce28167> in <module>
      1 import os
----> 2 import MySQLdb as sql

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'MySQLdb'
```

What do I need to do to work it all? Do I need a MySQL Server localhost even if I want to connect in an outside database? What is the requirements and how do I do it?
Thanks a lot!!

Comment: you need to install the [mysql-python](https://pypi.org/project/MySQL-python/) package using **pip**

Comment: If I do have to use it with a localhost MySQL Server, can I use it with Xampp?

Comment: I did that and received an error telling me to install the visual C++ 14.0, I'm gonna do that And try again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

About python tracebacks - usually they are really informative, so you can just copy last line and google it. In your case `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'MySQLdb'` it seems, that you didn't install package `MySQLab` - check this out https://pypi.org/project/MySQL-python/
In python you have a package manager -> pip, use it to install required python package from pypi.org.

You don't need a local MySQL server, if you have external database. But you do need connection data, such as DB_HOST, DB_PORT, DB_USER, USERS_PASSWORD, DB_NAME.
You will need this info, even of you decide to use MySQL server locally.

Last recommendation is to select any guide on YouTube and just go according to lessons)

Comment: I have those informations about the database, into the site you've shown me it seems that MySQLdb only works with python 2.7,I have the version 3.8 and the mysqldb version isn't released yet, I'll change my Python version and see if it works.